# How do I create a new migration each time I update the database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table from my Entity Framework database I have 3 entries:

```
201708082015111_InitialCreate 
201708082017162_Initial
201708082046380_AutomaticMigration
```

but in the project itself, I have just one migration file:

```
201708082017162_Initial.cs
```

I was thinking to delete the database and start over.

My main focus is how to create migration files each time I update the database from package console. For example, I create another model (therefore, another entity in my schema), so I want to run `Update-Database` and create a migration file in C# at the same time containing information about the updated schema (with the new table...).

Answer (score 0):

So, I made it work by applying:
`Add-Migration migx`
and then running `Update-Database -verbose`
Then I checked the __MigrationHistory table and noticed 201708082108002_migx had been applied.